# Share user session in Spring

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, session

I have web `spring MVC` web application that is running in Tomcat 8. This application is calling third party for form submission and do some processing on other server. After coming back from those third party server process, my user session is gone  & my application is being redirected to login page again.

I want solution that how can I maintain my user session?
Is there any solution using spring security?

I get the solution related my problem [here](https://dzone.com/articles/externalizing-session-state), but WAR could not deployed on the server.

Comment: could you clarify whether your app is running in cluster or it is deployed to single server?

Comment: it's on single server

Comment: "my user session is gone", is there a JSESSIONID cookie? what is session timeout? how long does this external process runs?

Comment: If my application request to  another server then my server session is gone .

Comment: is the JSESSIONID cookie has exp time set?

Comment: Have you looked at this solution using a custom ChannelProcessor? http://stackoverflow.com/a/7552769/1990536