# Does connecting to an HTTPS:// destroy all current sessions?

Tags: php, session, https, destroy

I'm currently building a webshop. When the customer pays he is redirected to a payment portal off site. The user connects to this payment portal via an https url.
After the payment is succesfull, the user gets redirected to my webshop.

Before the user leaves my website to go to the portal, he has some sessions active. I'd like to use some information in these sessions when the user returns to my page. When trying to retrieve these sessions, I found that they no longer existed.

I thought sessions would persist untill the user closes the browser? Does going from an http connection to an https connection destroy the current sessions?

Comment: please note a `secure` property in a cookie specification

Comment: I wouldn't have thought being redirected to any different site would destroy the session of previous visits.  There must be something else going on under the hook because that doesnt sound like very good browser behaviour.

Comment: So the answer would be, "no". Going to an HTTPS url should not destroy sessions. Apparently I'm going wrong somewhere else?

Comment: See @YourCommonSense's comment, it holds the key to your problem. Here's another hint: http://php.net/session-set-cookie-params

Comment: Doesn't the secure property let me send information ONLY via secure connections? I'm going from un-secure to secure, to un-secure again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can find an explanation here

[Session lost when switching from HTTP to HTTPS in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/441496/session-lost-when-switching-from-http-to-https-in-php)

Hope this helps you.