# Login form is not working after adding SSL certificate

Tags: php, ssl, authentication

I have a login form:

```
<form method="post" action="verify.php" name="loginform">
<table border="0" bgcolor="orange" align="center">
<tr><td colspan="3"><h1><b>Please Enter Username and Password</b></h1></td></tr>
<tr>
<td><label>User Name</label>
</td>
<td>:
</td>
<td><input type="text" name="user"/>
</td>
</tr>
<tr><br/>
<td><label>Password</label>
</td>
<td>:
</td>
<td><input type="password" name="pwd"/>
</td>
</tr>
<tr><td colspan="3" align="center"><input type="submit" class="submit-green" value="Login"/></td>
</tr>
</table></form>
```

and i have verify.php as

```
<?php
session_start();
include "dbconfig.php";
$user=$_POST['user'];
$pwd=sha1($_POST['pwd']);

$sql='select * from admin where username="'.$user.'" AND password="'.$pwd.'"';
$res=mysql_query($sql) or die('Login query error:'.  mysql_error());
if(mysql_num_rows($res)==1)
{
header("Location:index");
}
else
{
header("Location:login.php");
}
$row = mysql_fetch_array($res);
$_SESSION['admin']=$row['id'];
?>
```

is there any error here? I can't find any error. It was working fine till I use SSL certificate in my website. Now it is not working. I did a print_r request to know the values getting through post method. But only password is getting and also it is a wrong SHA1 value. Why this happening?

Comment: Your code is vulnerable to SQL injection.

Comment: How? I have used SHA1 encryption. Then how to avoid that?

Comment: Something else changed, it's not ssl. Also, don't use mysql_ functions anymore.

Comment: @Joel Have a look at [How can I prevent SQL injection in PHP?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/60174/53114)

Answer (score 0):

You are losing your session when switching from HTTP to HTTPS because the HTTPS session cookies have the `Secure` flag set on them, so that they can only be accessed via HTTPS. That means you can't transfer your old HTTP session cookie when you switch to HTTPS. You can try passing the HTTP session over to HTTPS.

Here's an example taken from [another answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/441496/session-lost-when-switching-from-http-to-https-in-php):

HTTP code:

```
$currentSessionID = session_id();
header('https://yoursite.com/login.php?session='.$currentSessionID);
```

HTTPS code:

```
// Retrieve the session ID as passed via the GET method.
$currentSessionID = $_GET['session'];

// Set a cookie for the session ID.
session_id($currentSessionID);
```

Obviously, you will want to make this more secure. This is only a simple example to convey the general idea.

Comment: but my login page is also HTTPS. then why this problem?

Comment: @Joel I believe it is because the form `action` needs to include HTTPS, e.g. `action="https://www.yoursite.com/verify.php"`. I also noticed that you are redirecting the user via `header("Location:login.php");`. You need to be more precise: `header("Location:https://www.yoursite.com/login.php");`