# setcookie() with PHP: change secure or httponly without changing path or domain

Tags: php, cookies

I would like to set a cookie as secure and httponly, but leave the path and domain as the default values.  How is this possible?  I am messing around with the following, but it doesn't seem to be documented to do so.

```
setcookie('my_cookie_name', $my_cookie_value, $expire_date,null,null,true,true);
```

Comment: Have you tried: `setcookie('my_cookie_name', $my_cookie_value, $expire_date,"/","",true,true);` ?

Comment: @Rizier123.  Not yet, but will try it.

Comment: Read the cookie using: $_COOKIE['my_cookie_name'] - then set the cookie using the values that you just read, using the new values that you want to replace? i.e. re-write it with your new values. 'Long winded', maybe - it will work.

Comment: @RyanVincent  I am not having difficulty setting the cookie with the value I wish, just setting the secure and httponly values without changing the path and domain.

Comment: I obviously misunderstood your requirements. sorry.

Comment: Other possible issues?: [questions/441496/session-lost-when-switching-from-http-to-https-in-php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/441496/session-lost-when-switching-from-http-to-https-in-php)