# session is not working with https

Tags: amazon-web-services, codeigniter

This is the first time i am doing the deployment from my side and am new to AWS. I have a project deployed on Amazon AWS server for testing purpose. I have set the domain name as: https://domain.biz

I have a login page here where once the user logs in successfully i am setting the userId in the session and navigating the user to dashboard.

In the dashboard i have added a function to check whether session set with value of userId. If the session is not set then i am navigating user back to login page. This is to block the unauthorized access to site.

I am facing problem here. when i was working with the server before adding ssl it is working fine.after  https://domain.biz session is working one page.and http://domain.biz works fine. When i have added domain to  https then the session is not working. What is the problem here with AWS? Am i missing anything.

Comment: A description of what "not working" means might be useful.

Comment: Did you installed the SSL certificate properly?

Comment: is that an example url?

Comment: ssl certificate installed properly.session working with http but if add https  session not working.

Comment: yes that is  exmaple url

Answer (score 0):

Check this : [Session lost when switching from HTTP to HTTPS in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/441496/session-lost-when-switching-from-http-to-https-in-php)

Since codeignitor is in php, I suppose this thread could solve your issue.